# IE8/9/10 Issues with Using Absolute Positioning for Hovering Effect

Tags: css, internet-explorer, hover, flicker

I am not very sure how should I describe / name the problem. This problem exists at the FB 'Like" and Twitter 'Tweet' buttons, on the upper right of the sidebar. In other browsers, it works perfectly (i.e. will be displayed and usable on hover), but it doesn't work in IE8/9/10.

Here is the link : http://billyf.site11.com/problem/singleblogpost-1.html

Here's the structure for each button :

```
<div class="button">
    <img src="" alt="image shown before hover" />
    <div class="meta">
    //here is the button to be revealed on hover//
    </div>
</div>
```

**How it works**
When a person hovers on .button, .meta will show (by changing it's absolute positioning), and .meta will contain the FB Like and Twitter Tweet button.

In IE, if you hover and move on the buttons, the 'Like' and 'Tweet' boxes will flicker and are non-clickable, hence they are completely useless. I tried z-indexing, but still doesn't work. I want it to work like the 'Comment' button (the 1st button on the left).

Thanks for any suggestion / help!

Comment: It would be great if you could share a short but working example in your question. That way future users can still benefit from the question, even if the linked web page is updated/fixed, (re)moved, etc. Note that you can edit your question at any time!

Comment: Added more information. Thanks for reminding!